# How best to model firm and market price and quantity adjustment in an evolutionary microsimulation setting?

Tags: microeconomics, price-theory

I am trying to create simulation of a simple industry micoeconomic market structure with a lot of nearly identical firms. They face an almost common production function except that 8 introduce small random variations in technology or materials cost. Pricing is set at marginal cost, except again with small random changes to represent strategic choice, or free will, or the like. Call it the scope of dicressionary pricing. Profits are calculatedin the usual way, but the firm is treated as having a short-term memory of both its profits and its dicressioary pricing decisions. Once the firm has three non-colinear values for price-profit pairings I turn off the offered-price randomization and replace it with a Nelder-Meade hill-climbing algorithm. Producer offers are summed horizontal and the price is set by intersection with an downward-sloping demand curve.

The problem I have been having is with aspects of price adjustment that seem unrealistic to me. Firms face these bang-bang solutions, were very small price changes cause the firm's sales to snap to zero. I would appreciate some advice on the sort of change most likely to result in realistic price-quantity-profit dynamics. Two solutions I have considered are, first, to switch from a perfectly undifferentiated product to a differentiated product and something more like monopolistic competition, or, second, to have prices and quantities set by contract so that only a small part of the firm's production is sold at the current price at any given time. I suspect there is some solution with costly price adjustment as well, but I have not been able to work out the details.

It may be that all I need from y'all are some good search terms for alternative models of price adjustment in markets with production. This is not a literature with which I am familiar. I have been hoping that this would emerge from this simulation effort, rather than be imposed on it. T
Or if I am going to see pathological pricing behavior, it would be nice if it were a sort of pathology we actually observe in some markets, like cobweb pricing in agricultural markets

Maybe I can figure out some approach to market pricing mechanism choice that makes sense. Seems like a good mechanism should let firms find optimal pricing close to marginal cost by trial and error, and a bad one would lead to a lot of wasteful entry and exit..

Right now I do not have any quasi-fixed factors in my production function, so no production-based long and short run. Do you think I need them? Is that the source of my firm-level instability? One of my goals/hopes to find and model realistic and robust firm behavior when input prices and technology are not precisely identical. Instead, I have replicated the raisor's-edge pricing and behavior that we see in more conventional models.